# Please call me when you're finished

Tags: grammar

> 1. Please call me when you're finished.
> 2. Please call me when you've finished.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

They both are.

[Finished](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/finished) is an adjective in the first sentence.

> [not before noun] no longer doing something or dealing with somebody/something

It is a verb in the second.

The first sentence is the more idiomatic one.